# please identify this switch

Tags: sensors

can anyone identify this switch type, please? I've been looking all day at various websites. I'm just looking for a very simple touch sensor, and this seems ideal

[image: photo of switch]

Comment: looks like it is custom made for a specific application ... it is similar to switch contacts in a mechanical washing machine timer .... the plastic tab on top would be operated by a cam ...  your question is an XY type question ... you are asking for help with what you believe to be a solution to an unspecified problem .... please ask about the problem that you are trying to solve

Comment: the robot I'm working on drives along a rail. I want to detect when it hits the end. it's a light robot so the switch needs to be easily-actuated, like with a levered micro-switch. a detector switch woould be ideal if I could mount them easily, but I'm using a 3d-printed chassis, so easier to choose a switch type that I can screw in place, like the pictured one.

if the pictured one is not something I can buy a load of, I'll just stick with levered micro-switches (unless, as you suggest, I'm solving the problem incorrectly)

Comment: another thing I like about the pictured switch apart from the easy actuation, is that it's flexible, so can "give" a little if the button is pressed beyond simple contact.

Comment: I will stick with levered micro-switches then, thanks :-)

Comment: thanks. I have a few optical sensors here, and did consider that (or lasers and a photoresistor) but thought that might complicate the environment. I'm trying to create a simple robot (and track) that can be easily replicated.

Comment: It looks like a Taster Button. Press the Black Isolation down to close the Circuit connected to this Button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a leaf switch. A search on AliExpress for "leaf switch" and sort by price gave me [this](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4001026309542.html)

Comment: Ayyy that's it! Great find!

Comment: that's the one :-)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a broken limit switch. Something like this https://www.zencnc.com/product/limit-switch/

Comment: no, that is not broken .... microswitches look different inside

Comment: @jsotola - If you've got an answer, please post it as an answer so OP can accept it.

Comment: @Chuck I do not know the name of that switch type ... I have seen that switch type before and the one in the picture looks like an unbroken one ... I have also disassembled various microswitches for cleaning purposes and all of them had snap action mechanisms that included coil springs and cantilevers